Post endpoint input request with coordinates in C#
Expected POST endpoint input request:
{
    "id": "some-guid-here",
    "orgId": "default",
    "hazards": [
        "bugs"
    ],
    "location": {
        "point": [
            29.0002,
            40.0124
        ]
    }
}

I need the model for it.
If I use following model:
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class Location
{
    public **List<double> **point { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string orgId { get; set; }
    public List<string> hazards { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
}

It doesn't work as it allow user to pass
{
    "id": "some-guid-here",
    "orgId": "default",
    "hazards": [
        "bugs"
    ],
    "location": {
        "point": 0
    }
}


List allowing user to pass single value and also multiple value. But my expectation is to pass coordinates(which is in the top of this file).
Pass coordinates and save into cosmos db

So what is they pass 0, you can write business logic to handle the case your Count before generating the JSON for your call. You can check out this JSON converter to handle one or multiple values for a List: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997172/1807452

In the backend, I need to verify request comes with coordinates values

I wonder if a List<System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate> would work. It feels like the doubles in your list are really their own type.

I don't find this package in VS nuget --- packaceSystem.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate
